# yeoman-generator installation error

Tags: npm, yeoman

I installed nodebrew, yeoman and 2 generators (generator-webapp, generator-bootstrap). But yeoman seems to don't know that generators:

```
$ yo webapp
Error webapp 

You don't seem to have a generator with the name webapp installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 3 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

(When that is `yo bootstrap`, similar error is occurred.)

So I run `yo --help`, but it doesn't show any generators:

```
$ yo --help
Usage: yo GENERATOR [args] [options]

General options:
 -h, --help     # Print generator's options and usage
-f, --force    # Overwrite files that already exist
```

But I run `yo` with no args, generators are shown:

```
$ yo
? 'Allo mehtats! What would you like to do? (Use arrow keys)
  Run a generator
❯ Bootstrap 
  Webapp 
  Mocha 
  ──────────────
  Update your generators 
  Install a generator 
  Find some help 
  Get me out of here! 
  ──────────────
```

Then I choose `Webapp` and run this generator, an error is occurred:

```
Make sure you are in the directory you want to scaffold into.
This generator can also be run with: yo webapp


     _-----_
    |       |    .--------------------------.
    |--(o)--|    |    Welcome to Yeoman,    |
   `---------´   |   ladies and gentlemen!  |
    ( _´U`_ )    '--------------------------'
    /___A___\    
     |  ~  |     
   __'.___.'__   
 ´   `  |° ´ Y ` 

Out of the box I include HTML5 Boilerplate, jQuery, and a Gruntfile.js to build your app.
? What more would you like? Bootstrap
   create Gruntfile.js
   create package.json
   create .gitignore
   create .gitattributes
   create .bowerrc
   create bower.json
   create .jshintrc
   create .editorconfig
   create app/styles/main.css
   create app/favicon.ico
   create app/robots.txt
   create app/index.html
   create app/scripts/main.js
Error  

You don't seem to have a generator with the name mocha installed.
You can see available generators with npm search yeoman-generator and then install them with npm install [name].
To see the 3 registered generators run yo with the `--help` option.
```

I referred to other questions and do `npm install --force -g webapp`, but it wasn't solved.

`yo doctor` said:

```
$ yo doctor
[Yeoman Doctor] Everything looks all right!
```

Versions:

```
$ yo -v
1.4.0
$ node -v
v0.11.14
```

Comment: Try updating your generators via `$ yo`.

Answer (score 0):

Along with using npm install directly, you can search for generators via the Yeoman interactive menu. Run **yo** and select **Install a generator** to search for published generators.

[image]